# Will a hidden-on-mobile iframe be downloaded?

Tags: html, css, mobile

Given an `iframe` and a media query selector hiding them, what mobile browsers will download the iframe content and how will this affect page load time?

HTML

```
<iframe id="foo" src="http://www.example.com">
```

CSS

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    #foo{
         display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As tags like iframe and img will always request the given source, there is a "normal" impact on the network as any other request. this means, that the request will be done at the time when it appears within the html context (incrementally).

to optimize iframe loading time, i would recommend to read: http://www.aaronpeters.nl/blog/iframe-loading-techniques-performance